# C# autodetect popup and click yes

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am creating a C# application where I am loading some websites into an webbrowser element. The website is loaded with:  myWebbrowser.Navigate(URL) or by clicking a link on a webpage.

My problem is that occasionally my application stops running and it uses huge amounts of memory. After a while I get the following message:
Stop Running this script?

A script on this page is causing you web browser to run slowly.
If it continues to run, your computer might become 
unresponsive.
Yes    No

I want the application to "detect" this popup-box and click yes to it, but I have no idea how to do this. Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Your real problem is the site you navigated to. The javascript in it has memory leaks.

Comment: Yes, but since it's not mine page I can't really change that, so I have to make some exception in my code to handle websites with memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

In VB6 you could use on the SHDocVw.InternetExplorer object the method silent.

I use

webbrowsercontrol.Silent = True

To block script errors.